# Passing encodeURIComponent(window.location.href), as "data-href" with Facebook Like plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm not sure how long this has been an issue with my Facebook Like plugin but I'm using

```
'data-href': encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
```

to pass the URL to "Like" when a user clicks the button. For some reason, the Like button doesn't show, but if I use a normal URL like "http://www.google.com" it does show up. Not sure what the issue could be because it was working fine before and none of the code has been touched in awhile.

Here's the rest of my code:

```
var fbLikeButton = $('#socialMedia-facebookLike');
        if (fbLikeButton.length) {

            var fbLikeButtonDiv = $('<div/>', {
                'class': 'fb-like',
                'data-href': encodeURIComponent(window.location.href),
                'data-send': 'false',
                'data-layout': 'button_count',
                'data-width': '90',
                'data-show-faces': 'false'
            });

            fbLikeButton.append(fbLikeButtonDiv);
        }

        var fbCurrentUrlArray = window.location.href.split('/');
        var fbChannelUrl = fbCurrentUrlArray[0] + '//' + fbCurrentUrlArray[2] + '/vgn-ext-templating/html/fbChannel.html';

        //fb like button script
        $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div><script>window.fbAsyncInit = function () {FB.init({xfbml: true, channelURL: "' + fbChannelUrl + '"});};(function (d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `encodeURIComponent`? In this context it doesn't make sense.

Do

```
'data-href': window.location.href,
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be necessary in case of foreign characters? Example: http://w3schools.com/mytest.asp?name=ståle&car=saab

Comment: @user1074378 the `location.href` automatically handles that, `encodeURIComponent` cannot be used on entire uris, just uri components (hence the name). You would call `encodeURI` - but because the encoding was already handled, that would just double encode and break everything.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks. Is there a reason why this would have worked before but is causing it to break now?

Comment: @user1074378 yeah I cannot guarantee that this will even fix what you are experiencing but it was definitely wrong in your code